# Convert a correlation matrix to a .SIF format

Tags: r, networking, matrix, correlation

I have a big correlation matrix from which I subsetted a matrix of size 1800X32. I want to melt this matrix to get a format like column1 value column2. Three columns with the first and third being the first row and first column of the original matrix and their cell value as second column, this for the entire matrix. I successful in getting the first and third column but not second.

Thanks.

Comment: See `?diag` which might do just what you're looking for.

Comment: It would be nice if we had some (reproducible) data and desired output.